# What is the meaning of "*&" in C++

Tags: c++

I was looking at manual of ACE framework and came across this declaration

```
int ACE_Stream<>::get   (ACE_Message_Block *&   mb, ACE_Time_Value * timeout = 0)
```

I'm not able to understand what `*&` stands for. I know * is for pointer and & is reference. Can any one explain what is the meaning of this declaration.

Thanks in advance

So as @NPE said *& makes changes to pointer propagate back. But to understand I just wrote down some code sharing it so that it can help others understand this correctly

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class DoSomething
{
public:
  int n;
  DoSomething(int i){
    n = i;
  }
  virtual ~DoSomething();
};

DoSomething::~DoSomething()
{

}

int dosomething(DoSomething * a)
{
  cout << "Got value from caller: (in dosomething) = " << a << endl;
  a = new DoSomething(25);

  return 0;
}

int dosomethingElse(DoSomething *& a)
{
  cout << "Got value from caller: (in dosomethingElse) = " << a << endl;
  a = new DoSomething(15);
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  DoSomething *d = new DoSomething(10);

  cout << "Pointer to DoSomething: " << d << endl;

  dosomething(d);
  cout << "After dosomething value of d: " << d << endl << endl;

  dosomethingElse(d);
  cout << "After dosomethingElse value of d: " << d << endl << endl;  

  delete d;
  return 0;
}
```

So as @NPE said here is out put of this

```
Pointer to DoSomething: 0x955f008
Got value from caller: (in dosomething) = 0x955f008
After dosomething value of d: 0x955f008

Got value from caller: (in dosomethingElse) = 0x955f008
After dosomethingElse value of d: 0x955f028
```

So indeed if I create a new instance inside function it will propagate only if I use `*&` and not just `*`

Thank you to every one for the answers.

Comment: Reference to a pointer?

Comment: Well it's a reference to a pointer (these things tend to be backwards in C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mb` is a pointer that's being passed by reference. This means that if `get()` were to change the value of the pointer, the change would propagate back to the caller.

Comment: That should even propagate if it was *mb right?

Comment: @copyninja: No, it wouldn't. If the function were to assign to mb: `mb = new ACE_Message_Block();`, the caller would not get the new pointer.

Comment: Indeed thanks for clarification! Is this documented some where in C++ standards? (lot of searching didn't give me any result)

Answer (score 6):

> I know `*` is for pointer and `&` is reference.

Correct. So what you have here is a pointer, passed by reference.

Comment: +1. BTW, I'm always amazed by how much people exploit possibility to insert white chars everywhere. I guess, that the cited code would look a lot readable if was written like `ACE_MESSAGE_BLOCK* &mb`.

Comment: @Spook Actually, I prefer sticking the qualifiers to the variable, it reflects semantics better: `Type *&refToPtr`.

Comment: And that's precisely, why I think that's a shame, that standard does not specify rules for whitechars around declarations - everyone has his own likes about this matter ;) The reason I rather would stick * to the type is because I started programming in Delphi, where a pointer to a type is a type itself (eg. PInteger or ^integer). That's why I rather like `type* &name` than `type *&name`. But these was preferences: one over another. Personally I usually write code like `type * & name`.